# The best Joomla forms module

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-component

I am just looking for some opinions on a preferable module to us efor Joomla. It must:

- allow CMS users to edit fields etc.
- store data in the database
- not have excessive mark up
- have easily editable themes.

I have used Breezing forms and some others, but they all seem a bit clunky and over kill for what is required.

I would like a fairly lightweight form module with easy customisation from a dev point of view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **Fabrik** extension. You can get it by go to this [link](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/forms/1659)

It's free and simple to use. Fabrik gives you the power to create forms and tables that run inside Joomla without requiring knowledge of MySQL and PHP. Then feed your data into Google Maps, Charts or an AJAX based calendar etc.It's my personal opinion, I have used this and found it interesting.

And others extension such as **RSform** ,**Breezing forms**, **Red form** etc. but these are commercial extension.

Comment: @IanJamieson yes i have used fabrik,it's really good

Answer (score 0):

RSForm! Pro is the best form module.
http://www.rsjoomla.com/

Comment: Would be good if you provided multiple examples and explained why they're good. Also, make sure you try to include a free one aswell, as not everyone wants to pay for Joomla extensions.

Answer (score 0):

**RSForms Pro** is a really good component for forms in Joomla. But it isn't really lightweight, it's fairly extensive. But still quite easy to use. ;)

I would recommend RSForms!

- Well maintained
- Easy to use and powerful
- Theming engine
- The price is low enough to avoid all the hassle "free" components can provide

Have a look at their website : http://www.rsjoomla.com/joomla-extensions/joomla-form.html